# Query a field in a nested document "as an array"

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a database with such a structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("x"),
    "T_K" : 750,
    "P_Pa" : 2026500,
    "phi" : 1,
    "composition" : [
        {
            "species" : "NC10H22",
            "mol_fraction" : 0
        },
        {
            "species" : "NC12H26",
            "mol_fraction" : 1
        }
    ],
```

And my goal is to find the objects with a certain composition (given by the field "mol_fraction"), let's say [0,1].
But if I try the following command:

```
db.prova.find({"composition.mol_fraction":[0,1]})
```

It doesn't find anything. How can I do that?

Note that if I use instead:

```
db.prova.find({"composition.mol_fraction":0})
```

It finds all the objects with one of the "mol_fraction" field equal to 0.

Comment: So if you've third one as "{
            "species" : "NC12H26",
            "mol_fraction" : 2
        }" in the same document above, then you don't need that right ?, you only need first two to be returned with that document in o/p?

Comment: I actually need a "non-empty" answer only if I look for the same exact composition, in the same order. So, in your case I would need no returns. But if I search for [0,1,2] it should give me the document. While if I search for [0,2,1] I would need a blank answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to design this query should be in a way that the array of composition can be passed dynamically.

Let's say, we have the following data in DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b2039cbfa696dcd9924a5"),
    "T_K" : 750,
    "P_Pa" : 2026500,
    "phi" : 1,
    "composition" : [
        {
            "species" : "NC10H22",
            "mol_fraction" : 0
        },
        {
            "species" : "NC12H26",
            "mol_fraction" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b20eecbfa696dcd9924a6"),
    "T_K" : 712,
    "P_Pa" : 2026501,
    "phi" : 2,
    "composition" : [
        {
            "species" : "H2",
            "mol_fraction" : 0
        },
        {
            "species" : "O",
            "mol_fraction" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b20eecbfa696dcd9924a7"),
    "T_K" : 713,
    "P_Pa" : 2026502,
    "phi" : 2,
    "composition" : [
        {
            "species" : "Na",
            "mol_fraction" : 2
        },
        {
            "species" : "H",
            "mol_fraction" : 1
        },
        {
            "species" : "CO3",
            "mol_fraction" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now, we need to search for composition: [2,1,4]**

The following query can get us the expected result:

```
db.prova.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $eq:[
                    [2,1,4],
                    {
                        $map:{
                            input:"$composition",
                            as:"composition",
                            in:{
                                $trunc: "$$composition.mol_fraction"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b20eecbfa696dcd9924a7"),
    "T_K" : 713,
    "P_Pa" : 2026502,
    "phi" : 2,
    "composition" : [
        {
            "species" : "Na",
            "mol_fraction" : 2
        },
        {
            "species" : "H",
            "mol_fraction" : 1
        },
        {
            "species" : "CO3",
            "mol_fraction" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

**What we did?**

- Matched the composition to search against the prepared composition. The composition is prepared from the mole fractions(in the same sequence) using the [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

You need the operator [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to do that:

```
db.prova.find({ "composition.mol_fraction": { $in: [ 0, 1 ] }})
```

**Edit: (searching by specific order)**

I don't know if MongoDB offers a 'filter precedence' like you said in the comment to this answer but, if you need to filter by values that occur in a predetermined sequence in your array you can do:

```
db.prova.find({ 
    "composition.0.mol_fraction": 0,
    "composition.1.mol_fraction": 1,
})
```

The downside here is that, if you need to find the sequence **0,1,2** (or longer), you will need to build your query dynamically, depending on the size of the list of values.

Again, this will work, but I don't know if there are more sophisticated ways to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately the $in operator still not satisfy my needs. The problem with it is that it finds all the documents containing (still considering my previous example) 0 and 1, while for me [0,1] is different from [1,0]. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I see... I edited my answer with a way to accomplish that